# How do I perform a search on a text file from a users input

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

The question I am trying to answer is

> 5. Query if a book title is available and present option of (a) increasing stock level or (b) decreasing the stock level, due to a sale. If the stock level is decreased to zero indicate to the user that the book is currently out of stock.

This is the text file

```
#Listing showing sample book details 
#AUTHOR, TITLE, FORMAT, PUBLISHER, COST?, STOCK, GENRE
P.G. Wodehouse, Right Ho Jeeves, hb, Penguin, 10.99, 5, fiction
A. Pais, Subtle is the Lord, pb, OUP, 12.99, 2, biography
A. Calaprice, The Quotable Einstein, pb, PUP, 7.99, 6, science
M. Faraday, The Chemical History of a Candle, pb, Cherokee, 5.99, 1, science
C. Smith, Energy and Empire, hb, CUP, 60, 1, science
J. Herschel, Popular Lectures, hb, CUP, 25, 1, science
C.S. Lewis, The Screwtape Letters, pb, Fount, 6.99, 16, religion
J.R.R. Tolkein, The Hobbit, pb, Harper Collins, 7.99, 12, fiction
C.S. Lewis, The Four Loves, pb, Fount, 6.99, 7, religion
E. Heisenberg, Inner Exile, hb, Birkhauser, 24.95, 1, biography
G.G. Stokes, Natural Theology, hb, Black, 30, 1, religion
```

And this is the code i have so far

```
def Task5():

    again = 'y'

    while again == 'y':
        desc = input('Enter the title of the book you would like to search for: ')

        for bookrecord in book_list:
            if desc in book_list:
                print('Book found')
            else:
                print('Book not found')
                break

        again = input('\nWould you like to search again(press y for yes)').lower()
```

i already have a function which reads from the text file:

```
book_list = []


def readbook():
    
    infile = open('book_data_file.txt')

    for row in infile:
        start = 0 # used to start at the beginning of each line
        string_builder = []

        if not(row.startswith('#')):
            for index in range(len(row)):
                if row[index] ==',' or index ==len(row)-1:
                    string_builder.append(row[start:index])
                    start = index+1
                    
            book_list.append(string_builder)
    infile.close()
```

Any one have an idea on how i complete this task? :)

Answer (score 0):

- 1. Get the titles from the `book_list` variable.

  - ```py
    titles = [data[1].strip() for data in book_list]
    ```
- 2. Remove any white-space from the `desc` variable.

  - ```py
    desc = desc.strip()
    ```
  - For instance If I'm searching for `Popular Lectures` book, but If I type `Popular Lectures`   then I couldn't find it in the `book_list` Therefore you should remove the white characters from the input.
- 3. If the book is avail, then get the book name and stock value from the `book_list`

  - ```py
    info = [(title, int(book_list[idx][5].strip())) for idx, title in enumerate(titles) if desc in title][0]
    bk_nm, stock = info
    ```
- 4. Print the current situation

  - ```py
    if stock == 0:
        print("{} is currently not avail".format(bk_nm))
    else:
        print("{} is avail w/ stock {}".format(bk_nm, stock))
    ```

Example:

---

```sh
Enter the title of the book you would like to search for: Popular Lectures
Popular Lectures is avail w/ stock 1

Would you like to search again(press y for yes)y
Enter the title of the book you would like to search for: Chemical
The Chemical History of a Candle is avail w/ stock 1

Would you like to search again(press y for yes)n
```

Code:

---

```py
book_list = []


def task5():
    titles = [data[1].strip() for data in book_list]

    again = 'y'

    while again == 'y':
        desc = input('Enter the title of the book you would like to search for: ')
        desc = desc.strip()  # Remove any white space
        stock = [int(book_list[idx][5].strip()) for idx, title in enumerate(titles) if desc in title][0]
        if stock == 0:
            print("{} is currently not avail".format(desc))
        else:
            print("{} is avail w/ stock {}".format(desc, stock))
        again = input('\nWould you like to search again(press y for yes)').lower()


def read_txt():
    infile = open('book_data_file.txt')

    for row in infile:
        start = 0  # used to start at the beginning of each line
        string_builder = []

        if not (row.startswith('#')):
            for index in range(len(row)):
                if row[index] == ',' or index == len(row) - 1:
                    string_builder.append(row[start:index])
                    start = index + 1

            book_list.append(string_builder)
    infile.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_txt()
    task5()
```